# MSSQL spatial layer import error

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I am currently working on a project in which spatial data are stored in a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database. The tables which hold the spatial table contain 3 rows and are:

```
RoomId - BIGINT, 
Description - VARCHAR(40), 
Geometry - geometry.
```

I use QGIS 1.8.0 for Windows and I use the tool for adding an MSSQL Spatial Layer. I succeed in connecting to the Server and I get a list of the tables which is as follows:

```
Schema: dbo
Table: tbl_lv1
Type: Polygon
Column: Geometry
SRID: 0
Primary key column: (empty)
Select at id: checked
Sql: (empty)
```

And when I click add, I get the following error:

```
dbname='gis' host='CAPDEV' user='qgisuser' password='*********' srid=0 type=POLYGON table="dbo"."tbl_lv1"(Geometry) sql= is an invalid layer and cannot be loaded
```

Why is this happening?

**Solved:** The solution was to add an auto-increment identifier to use as a primary key, because QGIS needs a primary key attribute in order to import data.

Comment: You might want to post your solution as an answer to the question and accept it. That way, other people will know that your case has been resolved.